# https causes immediate abort while http is fine

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, https

In my code, I have something like:

```
A = Backbone.Model.extend({
  // url : "http://localhost:3000/a"
  url : "https://localhost:3000/a"
});

var a = new A();
a.save();
```

When I use the http url, everything is fine and dandy; 
when I use the https url, however, I get the following error

```
{readyState : 0, responseText : "", status : 0, statusText : ""}
```

and firebug "net" tab shows 0 requests

Adding onto the weirdness, when I use fetch on two other models, both give "aborted" error but firebug shows requests made and failed, rather than 0 requests as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your site being served from port 3000 on localhost via HTTPS?

If not, then this won't work by default.  [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) prevents requests from being processed without extra work unless the protocol (http or https), the domain (all parts of it) and the port match.

Comment: argh, i thot i had it up but guess not; but i wish there was a better error message than showing "0 requests" in network tab, and an empty ajax error object

Comment: if you don't want to support IE, this is easy to fix if you "own" the server end.  but yeah, sometimes you get some crazy odd DOM error message, sometimes nothing.